# How to emulate a drum sound?

Tags: acoustics, fourier-transform

I've been working in a personal project which the goal is to create a digital drum. During my conjectures, I was thinking what is the best way to simulate the sound, below I will explain a simple idea that I had. If someone can show me a better way I appreciate.

The first thing I want to make it clear: I don't want to use recorded sounds, I will have some sensors of pressure in a pad and the idea is to create a sound proportional to the pressure applied to it.

My main idea is taking some samples on the Internet, from different parts of a drum, make a Fourier analysis and save the magnitude and phase of each frequency that compounds the original sound.
$$
Sound(t) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} Sound(f)
$$

When a pressure is applied in my mechanical system, the sound will be recreated through inverse Fourier transformation and will be multiplied by an exponential term, with negative decay.

$$
Sound(f) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}^-1} ReconstructedSound(t)
$$

$$
FinalSound = ReconstructedSound(t).e^{−t/α}
$$
The α term would be proportional to the pressure applied on the pads. More intense pressure would create louder and longer sound, while less intense would do the opposite effect.

I asked this question on math exchange, but the answer explained that my initial idea is a good starting point but probably the results will be frustrating, they also recommended posting the question on physics exchange.

Does it make sense this idea?

Does exist a more simple way?

Comment: What I would like to see here is the motivation for the general idea and each step. "Does it make sense?" Well, it depends what you want to achieve? Will sampled parts of a drum sound more like a drum than a drum? Probably not. I think what people here could answer, or at least take a shot at, is something like, "I start with some data, then run some process, and want this result, will it work" is at least answerable.

Comment: How is “I don't want to use recorded sounds” compatible with “taking some samples on the Internet”?

Comment: Most likely, different frequencies will have different decay times. In principle, the frequencies of a tout membrane of uniform mass are given by the vibrational modes, cylindrical Bessel functions that fit the boundary conditions. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Drum_vibration_animations

Comment: @G.Smith I would take the samples to study the spectral distribution, and, with this information, try to generate sound via software